# Messenger Bot Features

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

I want to develop an app where the customer could log in, pay, and receive some videos & pdfs.

I guess I have three options:

1) Make my own web app

2) Make a Facebook app (account creation will be with facebook)

3) Make a Messenger bot. A person would ask the bot what they want, the bot would send them payment link, they would pay and the bot would send them the download link for the content.

The reason I am thinking of this is that every customer will have to initiate conversation with my bot, so the bot will be able to e.g. send them messages afterwards (remarketing).

So I guess my question is: would this work from a technical point? And is there any other notes or recommendations somebody can give me? Just want to see what the internet thinks about this idea. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dominik,

Your general idea will work with a FB bot.   FB has some restrictions however:

"The Send/Receive API must not be used to send marketing or promotional messages, such as sale or product announcements, brand advertising, branded content, newsletters or the up-selling or cross-selling of products or service."

https://developers.facebook.com/products/messenger/

I'm not quite sure where the line is for users that reach out to your Bot in terms of up-selling.

If you haven't started yet.  See my article on getting your Facebook Bot up and running:

[Facebook Bots for fun and profit](https://medium.com/@matthewericfisher/facebook-bots-for-fun-and-profit-490245c3797c#.1gdej9wj6)

--Matt

Answer (score 0):

As an update for anyone else reading this, Facebook have revised the clause on sending promotional / marketing messages, effectively allowing it, IIRC.

> The restriction on promotional content has been removed for standard messaging.
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/policy-overview